# DB2 error: SQL0216N when trying to delete duplicate records

Tags: db2, duplicates

When I run the following :

```
DELETE  FROM db2Name.MyTable

    WHERE   (NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE) IN
    (
       SELECT NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE, RN
       FROM
      (
        SELECT 
        NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE, 
        rownumber() over(PARTITION BY NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE) RN  
        FROM db2Name.DELI_DATA
        WHERE NBR = 10 AND SALES_DATE = CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS         
      ) A

    WHERE  RN > 1

    GROUP BY NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE, RN
    )
```

I get error `SQL0216N`

I'm trying to delete duplicate records leaving one in the table when I experiment with similar queries, they're removing all records matching and leaving none

the table def looks like this

```
NBR  int
addr  string
market int
category string
sales decimal
Sales_last_month decimal
sales_date date
```

I can see that mostly likely the issue is in this clause not having the RN (that's why it is not matching the group by)

```
WHERE   (NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE) IN
```

but if I add it, it does not recognize it .... and it fails

Answer (score 0):

This could be simply

```
DELETE FROM (
  SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      rownumber() over (PARTITION BY NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE) RN  
    FROM db2Name.DELI_DATA
    WHERE NBR = 10 AND SALES_DATE = CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS         
  ) A
  WHERE  RN > 1
)
```

Comment: that did not solve the issue. it deletes all matches and not just duplicate records

Comment: It works for me. May be your definition of "duplicate records" is incorrect then.

Comment: my def of duplicate is any row that has The following columns the same (NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE) ... such columns will form my future unique/primary key. That's the reason I'm trying to delete duplicates .. so that i can create a primary key with those columns ... NBR, CATEGORY, SALES_DATE ...  so when i run the query it deletes all such records without leaving one of each which, then would be unique .... thanks for your help

Comment: I wish I had my crystal ball with me but it's at the mechanic for an oil change, so I can't really see what you're doing wrong. One thing I'm sure of is that the SQL has been tested and is ok.